# Jquery Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi is there any means of adding a new box as a part of sortable at click of button [on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwicher/Wmjsr/3/) using jquery-ui

For eg there are 12 boxes on click of button i should be able to add another box that is sortable and the id of it should be unique, so as even if one of box is deleted and added we have unique ids for saving to database.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Wmjsr/4/

here you go.

You can actually create a function to create the boxes on the fly, and reuse that in your add-button click function. Basically I just cloned one of the boxes and appended them to the ul. What you can do is after cloning(or if you followed my advice in creating the boxes on the fly) fix the id and value of the box. You'll probably need a boxCounter global variable to keep track of the ids you are generating and deleting

Comment: by making clone of the last i cannot pass the id... i need to have a new id for the new box this is what troubling me, As if i can have alert of new id i can save that using global counter how to pass id to the new box, if i use.. Can you please help me figure out this

Comment: Like i said above, you're better off just creating the boxes on the fly instead of in your html. make a function boxgenerator() method that will recreate the box's html and append it to your sortable list

Comment: OR if you're feeling lazy just put the clone in the boxgenerator method, assign it to a variable and modify the element's id by using theClone.attr("id", boxCounter++) or somethign